# Displaying data in Android from a MySQL database similar to a Twitter Feed

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, listview

I'm in need of a bit of help with regards to showing data stored in a mysql database in a ListView!

I'm aiming to have the ListView look similar to this screenshot:
http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_K6NH2gxxhAc/Swg0hqNDlTI/AAAAAAAAEQU/4qG-YjJRuBM/s1600/Android_ButtonOnListView.png

The idea is to create something akin to a Twitter feed using data that has been stored in a MySQL database. However, I'm very unclear on how to make this 'feed' from the data in the table. For example, I have two fields in my mysql table called Title and Content, how can I display these to the user in a way similar to that screenshot? Is ListView the best way of achieving this?

So far I have been following this tutorial to bring the data down from the database:

http://fahmirahman.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/connection-between-php-server-and-android-client-using-http-and-json/

I can post up my code so far if that would be of help, however as I haven't got a working ListView so it is only printing the MySQL data like this: [{"Title":"Hello World!","Content":"Hello again!"}]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#cursor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a PHP output of `[{"Title":"Hello World!","Content":"Hello again!"}]` you should be able to have the app retrieve that data, parse it, and insert it into those rows.

Here is an example of HTTP interaction between Android and a PHP page:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.website.com/page.php");

try {
    List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username)); //POST method adding username to request
    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password)); //POST method adding password to request
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    String result = handler.handleResponse(response);

    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

From here simply parse through the JSON Array and insert the items into your list.

If you're having trouble getting that JSONArray's data into your list, see this tutorial from Android's official site: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html